# Why are google use wildcard certificates

Tags: certificate, wildcard

I was wondering why Google are using wildcard certs as in *.google.com 
I was always under the assumption this was security bad practice as should a node containing the private key and certificate be compromised that would potentially expose the entire domain and the ensuing certificate roll would seem to me to be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I wish someone from Google would answer this, because that's the only way we'll know for sure!  I can speculate...

My best guess is that Google does not want to expose all of their hostnames via certificate transparency.  My second guess is that it might be to simplify maintenance; however, Google is very good at automating things so this reason would surprise me.

They probably have a number of security controls in place to detect compromised certificates and a lot of automation to easily issue new certificates and revoke any certificates they are compromised.  It wouldn't be a nightmare for them, because they're prepared for it!